# How to force a Python .pyw executable to open in a specific Python version?

Tags: python

I have a program that I wrote a while back and converted into a .pyw executable file. It worked fine but recently I installed a different version of Python so I could use an outdated library, and now my .pyw won't open.

I'm assuming this is because it doesn't know which version of Python to use. The only way I can get it to open is to right-click the file, and choose to edit in IDLE 3.8 32bit, then run from there. Its very long winded compared to just running the file from my desktop. Of course I can also use the command line but its also longwinded.

Is it possible to add a line of code to the file which will force it to open in a specific Python version? I need to be able to specify the version and also x86/64, since I have Python 3.7, 3.8(64) and 3.8(32).

Note: please don't get onto me about having multiple versions installed I'm well aware that its not ideal but it was necessary for a project I'm doing :)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Daweo They're talking about `.pyw`, so likely Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had installed Python with the [`py` launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) on Windows, you can [set a shebang line with Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#from-a-script).

For your case, you might want `# python3.8-32` or `# python3.8-64` or `# python3.7`.

Comment: Thats perfect thanks! `#! python3.8-32` gets it running like before